# Data Extraction from JMeter SampleResult Response

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

In the snippet shown below data and data1 are set from **different JMeter SampleResult Responses**. The challenge which I am facing is **during the processing of value1, I require the data from value** which is present in another class.

The value is coming from the response of JMeter SampleResult(say 1), whereas the data1 is coming from the response of JMeter SampleResult(say 2).

I am also using a validate file for BeanShell assertions which only processes the response of JMeter SampleResult 2 for validation purposes.

How can I get the data from value to use it for further calculations of value1?

> **Class C is an abstract class**

`class A extends C {
     @Override
     public String processValue() {
         ****Some code written here****
         value = getValue();
         ****Calculation of result done here****
         return result;
     }
     @Override
     public void setData(Object data) {
         this.data=(typecast)data;
     }
     private String getValue() {
         ****logic written here****
         return value;
     }
}`

> **value1 requires value from Class A for it's processing**

`class B extends C {
     @Override
     public String processValue() {
         ****Some code written here**** 
         return value1;
     }
     @Override
     public void setData(Object data1) {
         this.data1=(typecast)data1;
     }
}`

> **data1 and data are typecasted into different types**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JMeter you can put different objects in JMeterVariables as put:

```
JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
vars.putObject("data1", data1);
vars.putObject("data", data);
```

and get:

```
vars.getObject("data1");
vars.getObject("data");
```